# Apache Mod_Rewrite Regular Expression help

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to modify a URL and variable, and I'm not sure if I'm running into syntax errors or just using the wrong expressions.

I'm trying to turn this:

http://www.mydomain.com/trainings/12345

into this:

http://www.mydomain.com/remote.php?page=abcde&var=12345

The remote.php?page=abcde is static and will never change.  So just need to pass that variable and strip out the /trainings in the URL.  The 12345 will change.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /trainings/(.*)
    RewriteRule remote.php?page=abcde remote.php?page=abcde&var=%1 [QSA,L]
```

I've also tried some variations of the above with no success.

I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong syntax.  Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^trainings/([^/]+) remote.php?page=abcde&var=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: weird - i get a HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: my .htaccess is at the root of my site, is that ok for this URL? It seems like maybe it's actually looking for that directory?

Comment: Working like a champ.  I had to move around my .htaccess and add an override.  The regex provided above works awesome.  One question - it doesn't change the URL, the rewrite is masked - is there a way to show the rewrite?